# How to Delay The First FadeIn Event On Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently modifying this piece of code as apart of a project, it works fine for what I need it to do, however I want a relatively short transition period,but the initial div element only display for a brief moment and the fade process starts.

I was wondering if anyone could help me to correct this. Ideally I would like to set the initial slider timeframe or delay it from triggering the process,

```
var divs = $('.fade');

function fade() {
var current = $('.current');
var currentIndex = divs.index(current),
    nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;

if (nextIndex >= divs.length) {
    nextIndex = 0;
}

var next = divs.eq(nextIndex);
    current.stop().fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('current');
    setTimeout(fade, 5000);
});

next.stop().fadeIn(500, function() {
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
}
fade();
```

Comment: Couldnt you just do `setTimeout(fade, 5000);` on the initial fade call.

Comment: which bit should I add it to? still finding my way around this type of coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delay the function `fade()` from starting right away just do:

```
var divs = $('.fade');

function fade() {
....
}
setTimeout(fade, 5000); //here is the only change
```

At the end of your code `fade()` is executed right away.  Just add a timeout to it.  `5000` is in milliseconds, just switch that to the delay time you want.

---

Apart from your question, if you wanted to apply the fade function to objects only after you clicked them, you could do this.

```
 $('.fade').on('click',function(){//instead of click you could use any event ex. mouseover
     fade();//call fade function
 });
```

Comment: That's a useful snippet :)

Comment: Yes - like a charm thank you very much, exactly the effect i was looking for :)